# VLC doesn't run well in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vlc, multimedia, media

I recently upgrade my OS to Ubuntu 14.04, after successfully upgrading, I have some problems with VLC. Sometimes the volume is muted and when I forward or go back to media file then the sound is working. The second problem is that sometimes it shuts down immediately without reporting any crash or bug.

Comment: did you try remove and install again ?

Comment: Try running it from the terminal using `vlc /path/to/music/file` or `cvlc /path/to/music/file` and see what output or errors you'll get. Edit your question and include them here.

Comment: I have same problem. I suppose the issue is the graphical interface. No errors. adrian@asus:~$ vlc /home/adrian/Muzyka/Prince\ -\ Purple\ rain.mp3
VLC media player 2.1.2 Rincewind (revision 2.1.2-0-ga4c4876)
[0x25d4118] main libvlc: Uruchamianie vlc z domyślnym interfejsem. Użyj 'cvlc', aby używać vlc bez interfejsu. adrian@asus:~$ cvlc /home/adrian/Muzyka/Prince\ -\ Purple\ rain.mp3 VLC media player 2.1.2 Rincewind (revision 2.1.2-0-ga4c4876)
[0x10a2a28] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...